# Partial area of some tab items not firing tap event on sharpnado tabs

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabs

I'm using "Sharpnado Tabs" and having problem in firing tap event in middle "BottomTabItems".
I have 5 bottom tabs as you can see the attached photo and the areas outlined with black is firing tap event and changing the views accordingly. However, the areas marked with white, is not doing anything.
[image]

**EDIT**

The 5 tabs are spread evenly across the bottom panel. I have set the middle tabs' background to red to see the area they cover and where the touch is working. Setting `InputTransparent="true"` removes the touch event from the whole area of the tab.

```
<sho:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Grid.RowSpan="3"
                              Animate="False"
                              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedViewModelIndex}">

            <sho:LazyView x:TypeArguments="pages:ProfilePage" BindingContext="{Binding ProfilePageViewModel}" />

        </sho:ViewSwitcher>

        <Image Source="navigationbackground.png" Grid.Row="3" TranslationY="5" />
        <sho:TabHostView x:Name="TabHostLogo"
                             Grid.Row="3"
                             WidthRequest="200"
                             HeightRequest="60"
                             Margin="0"
                             Padding="0,20,0,0"
                             HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                             VerticalOptions="Start"
                             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             IsSegmented="False"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             TabType="Fixed"
                             SelectedTabIndexChanged="TabHostLogo_SelectedTabIndexChanged"
                             SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <sho:TabHostView.Tabs>

                <sho:BottomTabItem IconImageSource="homeiconselected.png" IconSize="20" />
                <sho:BottomTabItem IconImageSource="profileicon.png"  IconSize="20"/>

                <sho:TabButton x:Name="TabButton"
                                   IsVisible="True"
                                   ButtonBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                   ButtonCircleSize="40"
                                   CornerRadius="40"
                                   IconImageSource="navigationaddbutton.png"
                                   TapCommand="{Binding ProfileViewCommand}"
                                   Scale="2.5"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,15"
                                   TranslationY="-20" />
                <sho:BottomTabItem IconImageSource="chaticon.png" IconSize="20"/>
                <sho:BottomTabItem IconImageSource="moreicon.png" IconSize="20"/>

            </sho:TabHostView.Tabs>
        </sho:TabHostView>
```

Comment: If you **add code to question**, that helps make it clear what might be the cause. Show all xaml and cs code that declare or modify tab bar or its tabs. Are the white areas buttons? Or anything else about them that would use a touch event? Most likely those areas are "swallowing" touch events, rather than passing them on to parent. Try adding `InputTransparent="true"` attribute to exactly the white elements (but NOT to the tabs they are in).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have updated the question with code and little bit more details. The red area that you see is what each tab covers and touch is only working on the white area. It works fine on both corner tabs.

Comment: Touch works in white areas? You said black before. If you comment out the middle tabbutton, do the tabitems work normally?

Comment: That's right the black area works, it was a typo. And yes, if there are only two tab items it works fine

Comment: *"if there are only two tab items it works fine"* - not what I'm asking. If there are four tab items, but no middle tabbutton, does that improve how the two middle tabs work?

Comment: Ok it works when there is no middle tab button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `Scale` attribute. Unfortunately, that scales the entire tab area, not just the circle button. At `Scale=2`, half of each of the surrounding buttons are blocked by an invisible expanded tab rectangle (that surrounds the middle tab button).

As you discovered, at `Scale=2.5`, more than half of the surrounding tabs are invisibly blocked.

I did not find any way to work around this bug. (Other than not using Scale - but then the button is either too small or not a circle, depending on values you use for ButtonCircleSize and CornerRadius.)

I recommend raising this as an issue at [github Sharpnado.Tabs issue](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs/issues).

If you do, include a link in that issue to this SO Q&A. And add a link to bottom of your question to that issue - so people can track progress.

Comment: Yes, you're comments helped me narrow down the problem. For now I have adjusted it to work and this issue is already raised there. Cheers!